# postgres: could not access directory "C:/opt/PostgreSql/14/data": Permission denied

Tags: postgresql, permissions, windows, ssl

**Importantly:** This is on `Windows 10` and `Postgres 14` (for newbies, Postgres is also known as PostgreSQL), with Cygwin providing the `CLI`.

On a fully functional, up and running, and apparently perfectly happy installation, when trying to reconfigure to turn on `ssl` support in order to permit `JDBC` connections (as the new releases don't support the older driver methods), after providing `server.crt` and `server.key`, I made a few changes to `postgresql.conf` (which defaults to `ssl` params commented out) and a reload didn't work.

The server, still running as I only did a reload (`pg_ctl reload`), reported in the log (fluff not included):

```
2022-07-17 19:45:57.907 PDT [8980] LOG:  could not access private key file "server.key": Permission denied
```

So, at that moment, thinking I was the owner of it all, I restarted the server (again using pg_ctl). The shutdown went fine, but trying a restart turned out to be a mistake, apparently! From pg_ctl:

```
$ pg_ctl.exe start
waiting for server to start....postgres: could not access directory "C:/opt/Post
greSql/14/data": Permission denied
 stopped waiting
pg_ctl: could not start server
Examine the log output.
```

Curious! SO, of course, I checked permissions. NOPE, I was not the owner of the directory (IE installation - this is Windows!) so, I performed `chown <owner>` on the two server files and then tried.

With still no joy, I remembered the group permissions and, following the official Postgres documentation, ran `chmod og-rwx server.key` but that didn't work either! Arg!

Now, on attempting to restart NOTHING goes in the log and the user running `pg_ctl` gets this:

```
$ pg_ctl.exe start
waiting for server to start....postgres: could not access directory "C:/opt/Post
greSql/14/data": Permission denied
 stopped waiting
pg_ctl: could not start server
Examine the log output.
```

SO, I tried turning off `ssl` inside the `postgresql.conf` file... And STILL NO JOY! -slap-forehead-

My next step? I tried restarting the box - this IS `Windows`, after all! But 'nix and `Postgres` don't require such actions?! Frankly, I don't see what good backing out the `SSL` files does with the config turned off... And, I guess to NOT my surprise, `Postgres` did NOT come back following reboot! (Previously it has.)

And that's why I'm asking for help figuring out why this darned thing won't come up.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I figured it out.

I suppose this is a lesson for DBA types, like me, who don't use `Postgres` on `Windows` very often...

It turns out that while **I was logged in as a user who could successfully signal a reload of the server and shut it down, I didn't have permissions to restart it!** To my mind, that's just - uh - *"Mind Blowing!"*

As there's no `su` available on `Cygwin`, I just used an `ssh` session and logged in to the account that installed `Postgres` and, well, it came right up!

I turned `SSL` support in `postgresql.conf` back on and tried again. IT COMES UP!

When I tried `JDBC`, that failed with:

```
openVars(DriverManager.getConnection()) exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLExcep
tion: The authentication type 10 is not supported. Check that you have configure
d the pg_hba.conf file to include the client's IP address or subnet, and that it
 is using an authentication scheme supported by the driver.
```

But that's a problem for a different day! Happy DBAing, people!